# Change the element of a web page on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I tried my best to find an answer on the web but couldn't find any so I am asking one here.

I have three images of each bottle, one empty, second half filled and third filled, I am trying to fill the empty bottle on page scroll by replacing the empty one with half filled and then half filled with the fully filled one.

Can it be achieved by .scroll function of jquery ? e.g

```
$("#first-div").scroll(function() {
$("#first-div").hide();
$("#second-div").show();
});

$("#second-div").scroll(function(){
$("#second-div").hide();
$("#third-div").show();
)
```

Comment: yes not working as expected

Comment: then can you provide `html` too to play on this issue?

Comment: yes sure I will update the question with the html

Answer (score 1):

Your Working Demo Example is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/syvsoe3o/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#second-div").hide();    
   $("#third-div").hide();
});   
$("#first-div").scroll(function() {
   $("#first-div").hide();
   $("#second-div").show();
});
$("#second-div").scroll(function(){
   $("#second-div").hide();
   $("#third-div").show();
});
```

Here is another [JavaScript Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UUtV/1/) for both type of scrolling.

Comment: It works but it doesn't goes reversible e.g if I want to scroll back again ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with scrollTop

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height  > some_number && height  < some_number_2) {
        $("#first-div").hide();
        $("#second-div").show();
    } else if (height  > some_number_2 ){
       $("#second-div").hide();
       $("#third-div").show();

   }
});
```